# How to run a cron job with pipenv?

Tags: python, cron, pip, python-venv, pipenv

To demonstrate the issue I'm having, I will use this simple function, which lives in `/Users/X/Code/python/example/start.py`:

```
def say_hello(name):
   print("Saying hello to {}".format(name))

say_hello("John")
```

I'm using `pipenv` to set up my packages and environment. In this folder (next to `start.py`), I have four other files - `Pipfile`, `Pipfile.lock`, `.env` and `log.txt`.

When I run `pipenv run python start.py`, everything works fine and I get an output.

Now I want this script to run every minute, so I set up a cron job using `crontab -e` and here is what I initially had in there:

`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/pipenv run python /Users/X/Code/python/example/start.py >> /Users/X/Code/python/example/log.txt 2>&1`

Which was giving me an error dump in that `log.txt` file:

```
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.  Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/for mitigation steps.

This system lists a couple of UTF-8 supporting locales that
you can pick from.  The following suitable locales where
discovered: af_ZA.UTF-8, am_ET.UTF-8, be_BY.UTF-8, bg_BG.UTF-8, ca_ES.UTF-8, cs_CZ.UTF-8, da_DK.UTF-8, de_AT.UTF-8, de_CH.UTF-8, de_DE.UTF-8, el_GR.UTF-8, en_AU.UTF-8....
```

After a fair amount of googling, I came to conclusion that the environment was not setting the correct `locales`, so I added in that `.env` file which looks like this:

```
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Then I spent a few more minutes looking at the same error appear in the `log.txt` over and over again and then I realised that when I call `/usr/local/bin/pipenv`, it actually needs the correct `Pipfile` to load the correct environment. So instead, I changed my `cron` to this:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/X/Code/python/example && /usr/local/bin/pipenv run python /Users/X/Code/python/example/start.py >> /Users/X/Code/python/example/log.txt 2>&1
```

So technically, now it should be `cd`ing into the folder and THEN running the `pipenv` stuff, but I still get the same exact error in my `log` file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Call the pipenv and python from shell script

Comment: Nope, it's still the same thing.

Answer (score 16):

Try adding `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH` as well.  It seems that `pipenv` may need to call other applications in the path where it is also located.  When cron runs jobs, it doesn't have the same environment that you get when you log into a shell.

Probably easier to create a wrapper script to call from cron:

```
cd /Users/X/Code/python/example 
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
pipenv run python start.py >> /Users/X/Code/python/example/log.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this issue with a python program using [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and running via cron. As others mentioned cron doesn't have the same environment ie $PATH as the user entering the cron script data. In my case I am using a redhat environment that also has a software collection which provides python3.6 ( as mentioned in this post [redhat-py3](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/)).

Anyway my solution to the pipenv - cron conundrum was to use penv for creating the virtualenv with the required dependencies. And then use 'pipenv shell' to get a shell command that could be used for activating the virtualenv by way of cron and bash.
If I have already installed my dependencies with pipenv and created a Pipfile , then I can check the virtualenv using

```
pipenv check
```

If i already have a virtualenv then I will see the below messages.

```
 Checking PEP 508 requirements…
 Passed!
 Checking installed package safety…
 All good!
```

Then I can run the pipenv shell

```
pipenv shell
```

Which should result in the following

```
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
. /<path>/<to>/<virtualenv>/bin/activate
```

!!!Notice the period "." on the second line of the expected output.
This line can then be placed in my cron script (I recommend a shell script ). Which is then called by cron.

The final script run by cron and borrowed from @Chris Shaw would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
#or whatever shell you use
cd /Users/X/Code/python/example
. /<path>/<to>/<virtualenv>/bin/activate 
# you should specifiy the python version in the below command
#python2.7 start.py >> /Users/X/Code/python/example/log.txt 2>&1
python3 start.py >> /Users/X/Code/python/example/log.txt 2>&1
```

This solution is brittle, due to the reliance on a specific virtualenv, rather than the pipenv commands. So if you recreate the virtualenv , it will likely result in a new path. Which will need to be updated in your shell script. But it removes the reliance on pipenv to provide the shell environment for cron.

As an added note, I suggest adding an alert via email or something similar if the cron job starts to fail. Cron fails silently usually, and will happily carry on without doing what you want until you discover the failure.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it has been sufficient to directly run the virtualenv's Python executable, for example:

```
0 5 * * * /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-30iXwYpI/bin/python /home/user/project/script.py
```

As wordtronix has pointed out, you can get the location of your virtualenv by running pipenv and seeing what it prints on the console.

Answer (score 1):

I just added this file to my workspace, you could modify it if you got a scripts directory and take more advantage or the PIPENV_PIPFILE using the [scripts] in pipenv.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
script_dir=$(cd $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}); pwd)
PIPFILE=$script_dir/Pipfile
export PIPENV_PIPFILE=$(cd $(dirname $PIPFILE) && pwd)/$(basename $PIPFILE)
pipenv run python $script_dir/generate_avatar.py
```

Then the cronjob is just:

```
* * * * *  $FOODIR/run.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Potential issue: your cronjobs by default won't have access to your environment variables

I had a slightly different setup but was also trying to do some pipenv and crontab stuff. I solved my issue by using the `/usr/local/bin/pipenv` filepath, and also setting up my exported environment variables at the start of the cron script (found using `printenv`).